# Retrofit2 + Google Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Пытаюсь получать местоположение вот таким образом:

Retrofit(Interface)

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/geolocation/v1/geolocate")
    Call<GetGeolocation> getLocation(@Field("key") String key);
```

И тут обращаюсь к нему:

```
private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl("https://www.googleapis.com")
            .build();

    private API api = retrofit.create(API.class);

    Call<GetGeolocation> googleLocation = api.getLocation("KEY");
        googleLocation.enqueue(new Callback<GetGeolocation>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetGeolocation> call, Response<GetGeolocation> response) {
                Log.d("Log:", "OK");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetGeolocation> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Log:", "Error");
            }
        });
```

В ответ мне приходит

```
Response{protocol=h2, code=400, message=, url=https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate}
```

С другой стороны, отправляю точно такой же запрос через Postman

```
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=KEY
```

Мне приходит всё корректно

Postman

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `Query` вместо `Field`

Comment: При отправки Query методом Post выдает ошибку(должен быть Field) А когда пытаюсь отправить GET то гугл присылает 404 error

Comment: Покажите скрин запроса из посмана

Comment: Прикрепил скриншот

Comment: Попробуйте помимо query ещё `@FormUrlEncoded` убрать

Comment: Помогло, странно, почему FormUrlEncoded мешает?

Comment: А хз. Если интересно - наверняка в доке что-то написано. Ну или это какое-то требование протокола.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В приведённом вами запросе нужно использовать `Query` вместо `Field` и убрать `FormUrlEncoded`

```
@POST("/geolocation/v1/geolocate")
Call<GetGeolocation> getLocation(@Query("key") String key);
```